# test a java script boolean function does not work

Tags: javascript, function, boolean, undefined

I wrote a little code snippet to check, weather a date lies in holidays or if it is a normal working day. When I use the function with a date in holidays the function seems to return true. When i check, if the function with the date is true, it seems that no true value is returned.

Exspected output is:

```
Holiday!
Holiday
```

Real output is:

```
Holiday!
Working Day
```

What am I missing? Thanks for any help.

I tried to debug my code. The if-Statement in the function gets true, so i guessed, that the function itself would be true.

```js
//list of holidays
const ferien = {
  //Sommerferien: ["2022-07-25", "2022-09-02"],
  //Herbstferien: ["2022-10-17", "2022-10-31"],
  //Weihnachtsferien: ["2022-12-23", "2023-01-02"],
  //Osterferien: ["2023-04-03", "2023-04-06"],
  Pfingsferien: ["2023-05-30", "2023-06-07"],
};

//function to check, weather a date is in holiday or not
const getFerien2 = (date) => {
  //should run through all keys from ferien-Object
  Object.keys(ferien).forEach((element) => {
    //Test if timestamp of date lies between starting- and enddate of holiday "Pfingsferien"
    if (
      Date.parse(ferien[element][0]) <= Date.parse(date) &&
      Date.parse(date) <= Date.parse(ferien[element][1])
    ) {
      console.log("Holiday!");
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  });
};

//Test for a specific date 
if (getFerien2("2023-05-31") === true) {
  console.log("Holiday");
} else {
  console.log("Working Day");
}
```

Comment: I tried it. Same result. Somehow test is undefined when i do console.log(test);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're attempting to return from inside the loop, so the function never actually returns `true`. Use a Boolean value to track whether a holiday is found, and return that.

Other notes:

- I revised your date comparison logic to make it more intuitive.
- You don't need parentheses around single arrow function arguments.
- You don't need to compare the function return value to `true`. Just check it for truthiness.

```js
//list of holidays
const ferien = {
  //Sommerferien: ["2022-07-25", "2022-09-02"],
  //Herbstferien: ["2022-10-17", "2022-10-31"],
  //Weihnachtsferien: ["2022-12-23", "2023-01-02"],
  //Osterferien: ["2023-04-03", "2023-04-06"],
  Pfingsferien: ["2023-05-30", "2023-06-07"],
};

// function to check, weather a date is in holiday or not
const getFerien2 = date => {
  let holidayFound = false;

  // Run through all keys from ferien-Object
  Object.keys(ferien).forEach(element => {

    // Test if timestamp of date lies between starting- and enddate of holiday "Pfingsferien"
    if (
      Date.parse(date) >= Date.parse(ferien[element][0]) &&
      Date.parse(date) <= Date.parse(ferien[element][1])
    ) {
      holidayFound = true;
    }
  });

  return holidayFound;
};

// Test for a specific date 
if (getFerien2("2023-05-31")) {
  console.log("Holiday");
} else {
  console.log("Working Day");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i saw your code and it have some incorrect valuer.The  origin issue with this code is that the getFerien2() function is not returning anything when the date is not a holiday.So; the return false statement inside the else block is  returning from the forEach function, not from the getFerien2() function. because this error; the getFerien2() function is returning an undefined value in such cases, which is not equal for true and hence the output is "Working Day".

To fix this, you can modify the getFerien2() function to return false outside of the forEach function, after checking all holidays. Check this code with some implementations as more shorter with the same values as your code. With this your expected value will be the same as you ask.

```js
//list of holidays
const ferien = {
//Sommerferien: ["2022-07-25", "2022-09-02"],
  //Herbstferien: ["2022-10-17", "2022-10-31"],
  //Weihnachtsferien: ["2022-12-23", "2023-01-02"],
  //Osterferien: ["2023-04-03", "2023-04-06"],
  Pfingsferien: ["2023-05-30", "2023-06-07"],
  
};

//function to check, whether a date is in holiday or not
const getFerien2 = (date) => {
  //should run through all keys from ferien-Object
  for (const element of Object.keys(ferien)) {
    //Test if timestamp of date lies between starting- and enddate of holiday "Pfingsferien"
    if (
      Date.parse(ferien[element][0]) <= Date.parse(date) &&
      Date.parse(date) <= Date.parse(ferien[element][1])
    ) {
      console.log("Holiday!");
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
};

//Test for a specific date 
if (getFerien2("2023-05-31") === true) {
  console.log("Holiday");
} else {
  console.log("Working Day");
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).